# Automatically sync S3 with Hive metastore

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr

I'm using EMR with Spark/Hive to manage some parquet files in S3. When using a spark script to redact/remove (due to GDPR) some information, the EMRFS gets out of sync.

Using `emrfs sync s3://path/` I notice that some files are in red colour (MANIFEST ONLY). Shouldn't this be sync automatically, or at the end of a certain time? For me to fix this, I need to manually run `emrfs sync s3://path/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've end up adding an extra step to the EMR to perform `emrfs sync` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emrfs-cli-reference.html#emrfs-submit-steps-as-cli).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `aws-s3-client` to put or delete object then EMRFS will not know the transaction.

**Approach 1:**
You need to use [emrfs jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.6.0) in your action. Make sure the version is same as your cluster.

In that way emrfs will be in sync.

**Approach 2:**
Or if you have some hive table pointing to that s3 location you can also use spark read & write method. In that way you don't have to care about emrfs at all.

```
// Read from hive table
sparkSession.read().table("<table-name>")
// Write into hive table
df.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).insertInto("<table-name>")
```

Comment: I'm using `ALTER TABLE name DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(user_id='x')` to delete from the external table, as well remove the file from the system, `path.getFileSystem(sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration).delete(path, true)`.